# Unable to sort a vector member variable of a class/object in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, scope, pass-by-reference

As a course project, I am building a lottery machine simulator with different kinds of prizes.

I have a class called `LotteryTicket` which holds a `vector<int> luckyNumbers` as one of its private member variables. In order to access it, I have defined a get function as following:

```
vector<int> LotteryTicket::getLuckyNumbersList()
{
    return luckyNumbers;
}
```

One of the things I am required to do is check for winning tickets. A "Bronze" winner is someone who managed to guess all the correct numbers, but not in the correct order. In other words, the sets have to match. In order to do that, I want to sort both tickets (the winning numbers and the player's numbers) and then check 1 for 1.

I attempt to sort them by using the following functions:

```
void LotteryMachine::sortTicket(LotteryTicket& ticket)
{
    for(int i = ticket.getLuckyNumbersList().size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if(ticket.getLuckyNumbersList()[j] > ticket.getLuckyNumbersList()[j+1])
                swap(ticket.getLuckyNumbersList()[j], ticket.getLuckyNumbersList()[j+1]);
        }
    }

    cout << endl << "Sorted ticket " << ticket.getTicketNumber() << ":";
    printTicket(ticket);
}

//sorting by bitwise operations
void LotteryMachine::swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
}
```

I have the `cout` there as a test to see if my vectors were indeed sorted. So far no luck. I am suspecting I'm losing reference at some point, but I'm not sure where... or I might messed something up in my syntax with all these long dot-notation returns...

For additional context, the `sortTicket(LotteryTicket&)` function is invoked from within the function that checks if a ticket is a bronze winner. That mentioned function receives the `ticket` argument from a different function... i.e. a long chain of passing the argument, all with a call by reference (I can paste more code if needed.)

Any thoughts? The `sortTicket` function should sort the arrays and make it stick outside the scope of the function.

Comment: Please don't use the xor swap method, it has no place in readable code and is almost certainly going to be no faster than a temp variable.

Comment: @paxdiablo This seems like a sound advice I should follow. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vector<int> LotteryTicket::getLuckyNumbersList()
```

You made a copy when `getLuckyNumbersList()` returns since you weren't returning a reference.

Change into the following instead.

```
vector<int>& LotteryTicket::getLuckyNumbersList()
```

Comment: I was suspecting something like that. Wouldn't that return an address that needs to be catches with a pointer though?

Comment: @GilDekel: No, it returns a reference. That's what `&` means here. A pointer would be `*`.

Comment: YOU'RE AWESOME! THANKS! - I'll accept this as the answer as soon as stackoverflow allows it.